# Puppeteer js query and click a link inside of a td where td id contains

Tags: puppeteer, sizzle

I have to get the following selector.  There's several of them:

```
<td id="content_gvNewLeads_tccell0_5" class="dxgv dx-ellipsis" align="left" style="border-bottom-width:0px;">
                                    <a onclick="return ShowCallDialog(494038, 7);">2 Cloister Court </a>
                                </td>
```

I'm using puppeteer-select which allows me to use sizzle

```
  await select(page).assertElementPresent('td.Id:contains(content_gvNewLeads_tccel) > a');
  const element = await select(page).getElement('td.Id:contains(content_gvNewLeads_tccel) > a');
  await element.click()
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: an element with selector: "td.Id:contains(content_gvNewLeads_tccel) > a" not found
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for doing so ..
1. Using simple concept of javascript

```
 let clickButton = await page.evaluate(()=>{
      let node = document.querySelectorAll('#content_gvNewLeads_tccell0_5 a');
      if(node &&  node.length){ // condition is not much required but still checked
           node[0].click();
           return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }  
 });
```

2. Using concept of selector

```
       await page.waitForSelector('#content_gvNewLeads_tccell0_5 a');
       await page.click('#content_gvNewLeads_tccell0_5 a');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't put into account that is different on each one.   #content_gvNewLeads_tccell0_5 a.  That is why I am attempting to use a "contains". @Dheeraj Kumar

Comment: can you share complete table doc. I think **tccell0_5** will be varied on each rows. If yes then with few changes our code will be working fine.

Comment: It goes like this: #content_gvNewLeads_tccell0_5, #content_gvNewLeads_tccell1_5, #content_gvNewLeads_tccell2_5, etc.  But I don't know the exact pattern.  That is why I did contains then #content_gvNewLeads_tccell @Dheeraj Kumar

Comment: Then in that case at first you have to follow these steps
1. check number of rows in table 
2. start a loop 
3. Inside loop instead of **#content_gvNewLeads_tccell0_5** a use **#content_gvNewLeads_tccell+'i'+_5 a**
where i is loop iterator.

Comment: Naw man, why when you can use contains?  That's the point to my question.